# How to add and move UIImages as a group

Tags: objective-c, model, uiimageview, uiimage

I am making a board game and have a question about the best way to set it up in Xcode.

I want to be able to dynamically place pieces on the board (each piece is a new image) and have the user still be able to move the board around. So all the pieces need to move with the board.

In the storyboard I have set up a UIImageView as the game board image and have given the board a custom class (extending UIImageView).  I figured I could just add pieces to the board through this class and they would be grouped with the same view as the board, but ultimately this didn't work.

So my question is more theoretical: What is the best way to set this up?  Should I add pieces via the main View Controller, or through the game model (an NSObject)? Is there a way to group the new pieces (UIImages) to the board, so they can move together?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I think I would make the board a view in a scroll view -- you would then add your images as subviews of this view.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `UIImageView` is a subclass of `UIView`, you can just add the pieces to the board like this:

```
[boardImageView addSubview:piece1];
```

Then, when you move the board, all of the subviews of the board will move with it.

Note:  By default, you won't be able to interact with the image view, so make sure that you fix that:

```
[boardImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; // Or set it in the storyboard/xib if you are using it.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response!
I am using the following and it's being called from my board class, which is a subclass of UIImageView but it crashes.  Is it possible to have a UIImageView inside another UIImageView?

`code`
UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_bg1.png"]];
 [self addSubview:imageHolder];
`code`

Comment: I just tried it, and yes.  You can add an imageView as a subview of another imageView.  What line is it crashing on?  It would be useful if you can update your question (by clicking on `edit` beneath it) and show us the code that you are using.

Comment: So I went another way and got everything to work.  Thanks to rdelmar's suggestion, I made the board from a UIScrollView, which works perfectly.  And I can add as many UIImages to the scroll view as needed.  Thanks for everyone's help.